# Sum row vectors IF two or more rows in given column match (MATLAB)

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a 48x202 matrix, where the first columns in the matix is an ID, and the rest of the columns is related vectors to the row ID in the first column.

The ID column is sorted in acending order, and multiple rows can have the same ID.

I want to summarize all IDs that are equal, meaning that i want to sum the rows in the matrix who has identical ID in the first column.

The resulting matrix should be 32x202, since there are only 32 IDs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd totally approach this with [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) as well as [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).  Like the previous answer, let `A` be your matrix.  You would obtain your answer thusly:

```
[vals,~,id] = unique(A(:,1),'stable');
B = accumarray(id, (1:numel(id)).', [], @(x) {sum(A(x,2:end),1)});
out = [vals cell2mat(B)];
```

The first line of code produces `vals` which is a list of all unique IDs seen in the first column of `A` and `id` assigns a unique integer ID **without any gaps** from 1 up to as many unique IDs there are in the first column of `A`.  The reason why you want to do this is for the next line of code.

How `accumarray` works is that you provide a set of keys and a set of values associated with each key.  `accumarray` groups all values that belong to the same key and does something to all of the values.  The keys in our case is the IDs given in the first column of `A` and the values are the actual row locations of the matrix `A` from 1 up to as many rows as `A`.  Now, the default behaviour when collecting all of the values together is to sum all of the values that belong to the same key together, but we're going to do something a bit different.  What we'll do is that for each unique ID seen in the first column of `A`, there will be a bunch of row locations that map to the same ID.  We're going to use these row locations and will access the matrix `A` and sum all of the columns from the second column to the end.  That's what the anonymous function in the fourth argument of `accumarray` is doing.  `accumarray` traditionally should output a **single** value representing all of the values mapped to a key, but we get around this by outputting a single **cell**, where each cell entry is the row sum of the mapped columns.

Each element of `B` gives you the row sum for each corresponding unique value in `vals` and so the last line of code pieces these together - the unique value in `vals` with the corresponding row sum.  I had to use [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) because this was a matrix of cells and I had to convert all of these into a numerical matrix to complete the task.

Here's an example seeing this in action.  I'm going to do this for a smaller set of data:

```
>> rng(123);
>> A = [[1;1;1;2;2;2;2;3;3;4;4;5;6;7] randi(10, 14, 10)];
>> A

A =

     1     7     4     3     4     5     1    10     3     2     3
     1     3     8     7     5     7     9     9     4     9     6
     1     3     2     1     9     9     7     4     6     4     9
     2     6     2     5     3     6     8     1     7     6     4
     2     8     6     5     5     7     1     4     2     6     8
     2     5     6     5    10     6     6     4     2     6     2
     2    10     7     5     6     7     6     8     4     1     7
     3     7     9     4     7     7     2    10     7    10     9
     3     5     8     5     2     9     2     4     9    10    10
     4     4     7     9     9     1     7     8     6     3     1
     4     4     8    10     7     8     4     6     9     3     5
     5     8     4     6     6     3     7     7     4     6     3
     6     5     4     7     4     2     6     2     4    10     5
     7     1     3     2     4     6     4     4     4    10     6
```

The first column is our IDs, and the next columns are the data.  Running the above code I just wrote, we get:

```
>> out

out =

     1    13    14    11    18    21    17    23    13    15    18
     2    29    21    20    24    26    21    17    15    19    21
     3    12    17     9     9    16     4    14    16    20    19
     4     8    15    19    16     9    11    14    15     6     6
     5     8     4     6     6     3     7     7     4     6     3
     6     5     4     7     4     2     6     2     4    10     5
     7     1     3     2     4     6     4     4     4    10     6
```

If you double check each row, summing over all of the columns that match each of the column IDs matches up.  For example, the first three rows map to the same ID, and we should sum up all of these rows and we get the corresponding sum.  The second column is equal to `7+3+3=13`, the third column is equal to `4+8+2=14`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to apply [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and then use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to build a matrix that multiplied by the non-ID part of the input matrix will give the result.

Let the input matrix be denoted as `A`. Then:

```
[u, ~, v] = unique(A(:,1));
result =  [ u bsxfun(@eq, u, u(v).') * A(:,2:end) ];
```

**Example**: borrowing from [@rayryeng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32368346/2586922), let

```
A = [ 1     7     4     3     4     5     1    10     3     2     3
      1     3     8     7     5     7     9     9     4     9     6
      1     3     2     1     9     9     7     4     6     4     9
      2     6     2     5     3     6     8     1     7     6     4
      2     8     6     5     5     7     1     4     2     6     8
      2     5     6     5    10     6     6     4     2     6     2
      2    10     7     5     6     7     6     8     4     1     7
      3     7     9     4     7     7     2    10     7    10     9
      3     5     8     5     2     9     2     4     9    10    10
      4     4     7     9     9     1     7     8     6     3     1
      4     4     8    10     7     8     4     6     9     3     5
      5     8     4     6     6     3     7     7     4     6     3
      6     5     4     7     4     2     6     2     4    10     5
      7     1     3     2     4     6     4     4     4    10     6 ];
```

Then the result is

```
result =
     1    13    14    11    18    21    17    23    13    15    18
     2    29    21    20    24    26    21    17    15    19    21
     3    12    17     9     9    16     4    14    16    20    19
     4     8    15    19    16     9    11    14    15     6     6
     5     8     4     6     6     3     7     7     4     6     3
     6     5     4     7     4     2     6     2     4    10     5
     7     1     3     2     4     6     4     4     4    10     6
```

and the intermediate matrix created with `bsxfun` is

```
>> bsxfun(@eq, u, u(v).')
ans =
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Pre-multiplying `A` by this matrix means that the first three rows of `A` are added to give the first row of the result; then the following four rows of `A` are added to give the second row of the result, etc.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! I've borrowed your example to explain how the intermediate matrix works

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that this apporach does not work for my array, since it does not only consist of integers. The previous approach worked, though :)

Comment: I made a small modification (replace `v` by `u(v)` in the second line). Now it works for non-integers. Anyway, I'm glad Rayryeng's answer worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the unique row IDs with `unique` and then loop over all of those, summing the other columns: Let `A` be your matrix, then

```
rID = unique(A(:, 1));
B = zeros(numel(rID), size(A, 2));
for ii = 1:numel(rID)
  B(ii, 1) = rID(ii);
  B(ii, 2:end) = sum(A(A(:, 1) == rID(ii), 2:end), 1);
end
```

`B` contains your output.